# Install Specific version of cassandra on ubuntu AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cassandra

I want to install 3.0.10 version of cassandra on my EC2 instance. Basically I need to add a new instance to my existing cluster.

I have 3 nodes with 3.0.10 version installed.

When I try to attach new node to cluster the default installation steps installs 3.0.12 version. Then my instance goes in UJ state and never goes in UN state.

I am not finding any issues in the logs.

These are default steps for installation

```
1  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
    2  sudo apt-get update
    3  sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
    4  echo "deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 30x main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
    5  echo "deb-src http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 30x main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
    6  gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys F758CE318D77295D
    7  gpg --export --armor F758CE318D77295D | sudo apt-key add -
    8  gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 2B5C1B00
    9  gpg --export --armor 2B5C1B00 | sudo apt-key add -
   10  gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 0353B12C
   11  gpg --export --armor 0353B12C | sudo apt-key add -
   12  sudo apt-get update
   13  sudo apt-get install cassandra=3.0.10
   14  sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key A278B781FE4B2BDA
   15  sudo apt-get install cassandra=3.0.10
   16  history

ubuntu@ip-172-31-15-65:~$ sudo apt-get install cassandra=3.0.10
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '3.0.10' for 'cassandra' was not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Tarball installation

```
wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/cassandra/3.0.10/apache-cassandra-3.0.10-bin.tar.gz
tar -xvf apache-cassandra-3.0.10-bin.tar.gz
sudo rm -rf apache-cassandra-3.0.10-bin.tar.gz
cd apache-cassandra-3.0.10*
```

Configure your cassandra.yaml in conf folder

then for starting cassandra execute(from cassandra home dir)

```
cd bin/
./cassandra
```

or

```
cd bin/
sudo ./cassandra -R
```